# Hydra brute force not working for web app, but the correct password is in the list

Tags: web-application, brute-force, hydra

I'm trying to brute force an Instagram account I created to play with Hydra. I ran the following command:

[image: Screenshot]

Even though the correct password is in the list, it didn't work. This is the output I get:

[image]

Why does Hydra not return the correct password and username?

Could it be that I have the domain wrong? I tried changing the domain to the IP of the server, changing the type of request, but it still doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Copy/paste and use the code formatting tool.

Comment: Do you have permission from Instagram for these tests?

Comment: The typical reason is that you don't have the correct 'success' or 'failure' triggers. Use a safe, local, hackable VM to test on to work out your syntax. Then get permission to test live sites.